# Starting a sentence with "seeing as"

Tags: phrase-usage, usage

I am writing an essay and don't know if you can start a sentence with "seeing as". Here is my sentence:

> Seeing as I’ve chosen to examine the Wari culture a common theme between these articles is Peru.

Comment: It's usually rendered "Seeing as **how** I've ..." or "Seeing that I've ..."

Comment: I would say it is informal though. Why not use "*Since* I've chosen..."

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can use it to begin a sentence, grammatically.

**However**,

1. It is too informal for an essay, in the opinion of this US English speaker.
2. It doesn't make sense in this context.  ["*Seeing as how*..." means something like "for the reason of" or "because".](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seeing%20as%20how)  So you see how it doesn't quite make sense here - *because* of the fact that you've chosen to examine the Wari culture, a common theme between these articles is Peru?  You would use the phrase like "Seeing as how my theme was the Wari culture, I didn't examine the Nazca artifacts very closely."